# Shortcode EXCLUSIVELY on single.php

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I created a shortcode for adsense for my website's posts something like `[ads1]` which will display google adsense 336x280 ad. I put the `[ads1]` at the beginning of the post. To now, everything is ok.... but I noticed if I access my home page `www.websiteexemple.com` (on the home page I have 12 post displayed) then every post will display the ad that I put it at the begining. So how I can display that ad only on the posts (`single.php`) but not on the website homepage or other pages like archive, categories, tags ... etc?

Ps: I put the shortcode in `functions.php`

Pss: Until now I used quick adsence - a wordpress plugin that works fine adding ads with shortcode.... but I gave it up. I dont want to use any plugin anymore!!!.

My code:

```
function adsense1() {
return 'Here come the google ads code provided by adsense';
}
add_shortcode('ads1', 'adsense1');
```

Comment: Add the code for your shortcode handler in your question

Comment: Without a [mcve], we can't provide an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
function adsense1() 
{
    if(is_singular())
    {
        return 'Here come the google ads code provided by adsense';
    }
}
add_shortcode('ads1', 'adsense1');
```

Additionally, you can pass post-type as a `is_singular` param like this `is_singular('post')`.